# A word for when one thanks another for being exact?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idioms

So I sent an email to a Prof. asking for an invitation letter for a position. Now I receive his reply, and I am fascinated by the exactitude and precision in his reply. It is obvious that he has taken time to read the position flier exactly. So he has a clear mind about the requirements, the deadlines, etc.

I want to thank him and thanks his thorough considerations, his exactitude, his precision. What should I say? What is the most idiomatic way to do so? Here are  some suggestions. Which one is better? Or, you might have better suggestion?

1. > Thanks for your exactitude?
2. > Thanks for your thorough considerations?
3. > Thanks for your precision?

Comment: Hi @sasan, thanks for the interesting question.  Just one comment, though, "consideration" is more commonly used as a non-count noun.  Saying "considerations" sounds a little awkward.

Comment: @Karlomanio Would you mention a reference for your view?

Comment: There are other uses of consideration that are considered count, but this one is considered non-count.  From the Learner's Dictionary, http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/consideration
1 
[noncount] : careful thought : the act of thinking carefully about something you will make a decision about
You should give some serious consideration to your retirement plans.
After careful consideration, he agreed to their requests.
Her suggestion is still under consideration by the committee. [=the people on the committee are still thinking about and discussing her suggestion]

Comment: Thank you for meeting my expectations so thoroughly. Thank you for the thoroughness of your reply. Thank you for such a thorough reply. The person was thorough, not exact or precise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to thanks such a person is:

> 1. Thank you for being so scrupulous.
> 2. Thank you for your scrupulous reply.

But I am not sure which one is the better choice.

The following sense is to the point:

> **[scru·pu·lous](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHZL_enIR762IR762&ei=fBwEXJejJcn3kwWR-474Aw&q=scrupulous&oq=scrupulous&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39l2j0i67j0j0i67j0i20i263j0l3j0i67.17569.28044..28582...1.0..1.853.3862.3-1j3j1j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i10.GcnBErz9uqE)**  (of a person or process) diligent, thorough, and extremely attentive to details.
>
> "the research has been carried out with scrupulous attention to
> detail"
>
> synonyms: careful, meticulous, painstaking, thorough, assiduous,
> sedulous, attentive, conscientious, punctilious, searching, close,
> minute, rigorous, particular, strict
>
> "scrupulous attention to detail"

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

The word [**meticulous**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/meticulous) comes to mind, for example:

"Thank you for your meticulously detailed reply",

or simply:

"Thank you for your meticulous reply",

These would express gratitude for what you feel to be the professor's exceptionally careful attention to detail. However, there is also a question of tone. If I were writing thanks, I would be wary of 'going over the top' - seeming sycophantic, or appearing to attempt flattery.

I think I would restrict myself to:

"Thank you for your detailed reply".

Or maybe:

"Thank you for your helpfully detailed reply".

Which both seem less emotive, and more businesslike, to me.. as if I would naturally *expect* the professor to be as precise has he has been, while expressing gratitude for his professionalism.

Comment: I am not entirely sure if meticulous is entirely the right sentiment for precision, but to the extent that it might help your answer I would guess that meticulousness is a particularly good inflection for a context of gratitude and [this book has an interesting exemplary sentence](https://books.google.com/books?id=EHw6DwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA8&dq=%22thank%20you%20for%20your%20meticulousness%22&pg=PA8#v=onepage&q=%22thank%20you%20for%20your%20meticulousness%22&f=false) which may help to demonstrate the point.

Comment: @Tonepoet.. thank you for the example!  This is purely personal.. I prefer my English to be as plain as possible, and tend to write as I speak. So I would find it hard to use 'meticulousness' .. simply because I couldn't get my tongue round it!

Comment: To me 'meticulous' is too negatively connotated for being in a positively frame reply.

Comment: @johann_ka  Thanks for pointing this out - it truly surprises me. There must be a cultural distinction here - in my part of UK English language culture, there is no negative connotation of  say, 'pedantry' or 'officiousness' , which is what I imagine you might mean.

Comment: @RobinBetts Eventually because of modern office language culture. Because, in the English standard dictionaries 'meticulous' is shown as 'approving' but in the office - at least in my experience - it is deemed as 'a slight drag'. As two people have already upvoted my comment, I'm probably not the only one. We should start a campaign and educate people that 'meticulous' is, by definition, rather positively connotated.

Comment: I would never tell a professor to whom I had posed a question, that his or her reply ( I assume via email) had been meticulous. meticulous is not negatively connoted. Meticulous is how well someone does their housework, other work or investigation or suchlike. Not how thoroughly a professor answers a question. meticulous research, OK, meticulously clean, OK, meticulous room, OK. meticulous answer, not OK. [sorry, being a bayitch]

Comment: @Lambie I am so surprised by this! (I'm not saying anyone is wrong.. ) For me, the nuance of 'meticulous' is of the care and effort put into precision, as much as precision itself, and so the implication is of gratitude for care. I seem to be in a minority, though, despite the dictionary definitions. Perhaps it's generational?

Comment: Right, well, if the professor lectures on archaeology, the phrase could hit the mark.  "meticulously detailed reply" sounds pretty as a description to a friend about a reply but not pragmatically suited to a general mode of expressing a thank you.  Generational? Hmm. Probably more situational.  :)

Answer (score 1):

The OP wrote: I am fascinated by the exactitude and precision in his reply.

I write: We generally might say **thorough** here, not exact or precise.

- Thank you for your **thorough reply**.
- Thank you for the **thoroughness of your reply**.
- Thank you for replying **so thoroughly** to my question.
- I appreciate your taking the time to send me such a thorough reply.

**One would want to avoid qualifying a professor's answer as precise or accurate** or any adjective that sound like those.  That ***could even be taken*** as insulting.

The point is that she or he took the time to answer your question in full.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this question will inevitably have a personal taste component, rather than an objective answer. In that respect, like the previous answer, may I suggest you use "Thank you" instead of "Thanks" in your reply - it sounds slightly better to me.

One option I would put forward is to separate the *thanks* from a more elaborate expression of appreciation: while I agree you don't want to end up with flattery, I think it is valid to express one's gratefulness about something which exceeds expectations. Something like (taking your examples as a starting point):

> Thank you for your detailed reply, I sincerely appreciate your thorough consideration of my request

Answer (score 0):

I think your option 2 is the strongest based on your stated intent.

Here are some alternatives in that same vein, if they are helpful.

```
a) Thank you for your thoughtfulness.
b) Thank you for your carefully considered answer.
c) I appreciate the effort you put into crafting an answer.
```

If you can go with more a slightly longer version (a good way to indicate sincerity and escape what looks like a rote response), you could add a second sentence like:

```
Your time and your expertise offered me a unique perspective on [the topic].
```

Some such explanation of the actual benefit you received can make the statement much more personal.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider ***painstaking***.

> Thank you for your ***painstaking*** response!

ODO:

> **[painstaking](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/painstaking)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>   Done with or employing great care and thoroughness.
>
> ‘painstaking attention to detail’

Usage examples:

> [Google Search for "painstaking response"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22painstaking%20response%22)